# Django forms: How do I make it necessary to fill out one field but not possible to fill out both?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to have an option to link to a file OR upload a file. Obviously you can't do both. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Take a look at the Django docs about the `clean` function for cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

You can then, inside the `clean`, do a check for the values of the two fields.

Something along these lines:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class MyForm(forms.Form):

    field_1 = forms.CharField(required=False)

    field_2 = forms.CharField(required=False)

    def clean(self):

        # Get the field values submitted
        cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
        field_1_data = cleaned_data.get('field_1')
        field_2_data = cleaned_data.get('field_2')

        # Check that only one field is filled out.
        if field_1_data and field_2_data:
            raise ValidationError('Only fill out one field please.', code='invalid')
```